# What is the purpose of "\c" in perl?

Tags: perl

What does \c do in perl? I tried looking for it everywhere but the support for perl is not so good as compared to other languages. Everywhere that i looked it showed that it is a control statement and its syntax is \cX where x can be any character. But that doesn't explain anything. So can anyone please explain what does it do and how to use it?

Comment: Try `perl -l -e 'print "\cC"'` — it prints a control-C and a newline.  Now what do you think `'\cX'` means?  (It doesn't stipulate alphabetic only because the ASCII code set has `@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_` as consecutive character codes, and you can use `perl -l -e 'print "\c_"'` to print 0x1F or control-underscore or 'unit separator', etc.)

Comment: See also the section *"Quote and Quote-like Operators"* in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators).

Comment: " the support for perl is not so good as compared to other languages". Is that really true? I generally find that the [Perl documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/) is pretty good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring comments to an answer.*</sup>

Try:

```
perl -l -e 'print "\cC"'
```

It prints a control-C and a newline (you might need to pipe it to `od -c` or `xxd -g 1` or some similar data dumper). Now what do you think `'\cX'` means?

The documentation doesn't stipulate alphabetic only because the ASCII code set has `@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_` as consecutive character codes, and you can use, for example:

```
perl -l -e 'print "\c_"'
```

to print 0x1F or control-underscore or 'unit separator', etc.  You can use lower-case or upper-case letters, but only the non-alphabetic characters shown (`"\c@"` is the null byte, `'\0'` in C).  Note that the backslash needs special treatment.  The escape sequence cannot appear at the end of a string.

```
perl -l -e 'print "\c\X"'
```

This prints 0x1C (control-backslash) followed by X and a newline.  I guess that if you need that at the end of a string, you'll have to use a substring operation:

```
perl -l -e 'print substr("\c\X", 0, 1)'
```

You can also use `\c?` to print the DEL character, 0x7F, on ASCII-based platforms (see the manual for what it means under EBCDIC if that is a problem for you, or your curiosity is piqued).

As mentioned by[Håkon Hægland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2173773/h%c3%a5kon-h%c3%a6gland) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39562777/what-is-the-purpose-of-c-in-perl#comment66436521_39562777), you can find the details under [Quote and quote-like operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) in the [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) documentation.

Comment: Note that the character following `\c` could once be just about any character. It become deprecated to use non-printable ASCII in 5.20, and it became an error in 5.22.

Comment: @ikegami: Interesting; I was looking at the 5.24 documentation since that's what is current, and I didn't notice it mentioning that (but I didn't scrutinize the whole section completely, so I may have missed what's blatantly obvious).  Thanks for the extra info.

Comment: It's not mentioned in 5.24's docs because it was removed in 5.22.